# Juniper Remote Desktop Connection Freezing under Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, vpn, juniper

I recently purchased a Sony Vaio Pro 13 Ultrabook with Windows 8 and I have an issue when connected to the VPN at work where it freezes every few minutes while using Remote Desktop through Juniper. After about 10 seconds it displays a dialog about the connection being lost and it retries and the connection is restored. Sometimes it happens so frequently that it is almost unusable.

I found a forum posting where several users are experiencing a similar issue with Windows 8 and Juniper:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9fd4d6d5-1adc-494d-a916-0032f3e08789/remote-desktop-client-on-windows-8-drop-connection

I tried suggestions from this blog post but they did not resolve the issue:

http://kevinmarquette.blogspot.ca/2012/10/windows-8-and-juniper-rdp-vpn.html

Answer (score 1):

The [hotfix associated with KB2897602](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2897602), "TCP connections that use ephemeral loopback addresses are dropped suddenly in Windows", has fixed my Windows 8 RDP client freeze problems.

> #### Symptoms
>
> You run an application that connects remotely by using a TCP connection on a computer that's running Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, or Windows Server 2012 R2. If the TCP connection uses ephemeral (short-lived) loopback addresses, the connection may be dropped suddenly after 40 to 50 seconds. However, the TCP connection is still "live" from the client side. In this situation, the application does not maintain the remote connection.

Answer (score -1):

Something I found that seems to help a lot but doesn't necessarily resolve the issue completely is to change the color depth to 16-bit. Since making this change I have found my connection to be faster and I rarely encounter the connection loss issue.

You can set this on the Juniper page after you login by clicking Preferences > General as shown in this screen shot. You need to set this before launching your terminal session and you cannot use it with preset terminal session links. It only works with new terminal session connections that you manually enter the computer name for and launch from the main page. [image: Juniper Color Depth Setting]